# Open IE Explorer Bar By changing registry

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar, explorer

I am trying to implement Internet Explorer by following the steps in below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753590.aspx

everything is done, now I want, when I open IE, that toolbar should open on its own.

I assume I will have to change some registry value, how ever I am not able to get, how I can achieve that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the key that handles if a toolbar is visible or not is located here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars\<Your GUID>\ please verify.

Comment: here, there is not any key which says visible or not, one is default key present and another key is BarSize